# Unity SetPositionAndRotation doesn't work

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I want to make a 2D project with a character that instant moves by some pixels and rotates by 90°. I tried this:

```
void Update() {
        transform.SetPositionAndRotation(new Vector2(transform.position.x + 1, transform.position.y), new Quaternion(transform.eulerAngles.x + 1, 0, 0, 0));
        Debug.Log("Rotation: " + transform.eulerAngles.x);
    }
}
```

The movement works fine, but the rotation doesn't. I'm pretty sure that `transform.eulerAngles.x` isn't the right variable.

1. The character rotates only one time and that makes sense because the debug console keeps saying that `transform.eulerAngles.x` is zero. (so 0 + 1 = 1).
2. It rotates by 180° instead of 90°, and if I put 0.5 instead of 1 unity says that 0.5 is a double.

Answer (score 0):

[Quaternion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quaternion) is quite complex and work different to how you are trying to use it. Especially

```
transform.eulerAngles.x
```

is not the same as

```
transform.rotation.x
```

you can't simply mix euler and Quaternion space values!

For your rotation rather use e.g.

```
transform.rotation * Quaternion.Euler(90, 0, 0)
```

which rotates the current rotation about 90° on the X-axis (see [Quaternion operator `*`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Quaternion-operator_multiply.html))

Never touch Quaternion values manually if you don't know exactly what you are doing